# MODX - где в шаблоне подключается css

Tags: modx

Есть чанк head, в котором подключаются стили:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А при получении странички с сервера появляется файл стилей web.css, который мне нужно убрать.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все перекопал - не нашел, где он подключается. Прошу помощи - куда рыть, в каком направлении?

В gallery только эти настройки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте, думаю, данный стиль подгружается скриптом компонента "gallery". Посмотрите в "Системных настройках", и выберите gallery, возможно у компонента есть возможность отключения подгрузки css. Или просмотрите в админке код созданных элементов (чанки, сниппеты, плагины) при установки gallery и просмотрите код других элементов gallery (в папках public_html/assets/components/ и  public_html/assets/components/)

Comment: спасибо, буду рыть

Answer (score 0):

Решение: ``` [[Gallery? &useCss=``]] ```

[Ссылка](https://forums.modx.com/thread/50652/modified-usecss-parameter-for-gallery-snippet-call)